# Fan and venturi effect

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy, power

A simple calculation shows the power $P$ you can get from wind at speed $v$ passing through an area $A$ is (in Watts) 
$$P = 1.23\,v^3 \frac{A}{2}.$$

Using the above equation and taking the Venturi Effect in a very simple way, we know that half the area would produce wind with twice the speed i.e. if you collect the fluid at $v_1$ through a tube of cross-section area $A_1$, then you get $2v_1$ if the cross-section area is reduced to $A_1/2$.

So instead of collecting from an area A, you could divide the area by ten for example, and get a 10 times faster wind speed. From there and the power get from wind you have infinite power :D. A fan could be an infinite source of energy (after it has been initiated).

So I suppose I am missing a point. My question is what am I misssing?

(I guess the pressure needed to "push" the air through a tunnel would be so much that the fan would just do nothing or you would need that much energy to fight that.)

Comment: Wind speed is an independent variable for a wind turbine, meaning that you have no control over it, and you can't arbitrarily increase it with the geometry of the device that you are using.

Comment: I don't want to increase the wind speed of the device. I want to "push" the air trough a tunnel. And i want to know why the gain of speed from that cannot be a way to produce energy. (And i know it cant cause it would violate all the law of normality). And thanks @ohneVal for the edit, this post looks so beautiful).

Comment: @PauZen "So instead of collecting from an area A, you could divide the area by ten for example, and get a 10 times faster wind speed." Why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done and it's already under research. Just google with "application of venturi effect in wind turbines" and you can see a lot of papers there. It's an accepted fact that the velocity of wind increases when a venturi is used. Papers with experimental results are already available.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/386030)

Comment: So would the OP get infinite power using a venturi tube? If not, why not?